# How can I use the Cl task in msbuild?

Tags: visual-c++, msbuild, visual-studio-2019

I had the need to run cl.exe from an msbuild target for shenanigans. So I turned to the `Cl` task, since that seemed to be the way to do it.

```
<Cl
        ObjectFileName="$(TLHIntermediatePath)%(TLHImport.FileName).tlh.obj"
        SuppressStartupBanner="true"
        MultiProcessorCompilation="false"
        Sources="$(_TLHImportFileName)"
      />
```

But it keeps giving me the error:

```
TLHImport.targets(51,5): error MSB4018: Microsoft.Build.Shared.InternalErrorException:
MSB0001: Internal MSBuild Error: CL.exe unexpectedly not a rooted path
```

I even tried copying piles of parameters from the Cl task invocation of the `ClCompile` target in C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\MSBuild\Microsoft\VC\v160\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets, but to no avail.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out! Since the built-in `ClCompile` target worked,
I continued to copy elements from there until I found the crucial difference:
when I added `DependsOnTargets="SelectClCompile"` to my target, it started working.

I didn't change the parameters of the task itself, so it must be fetching whatever it is under the hood. Most likely it sets some property that `Cl` needs. I didn't look deeper into which part of `SelectClCompile` was key, because when depending on the internal targets, the higher level you depend on, the less likely it is to change in new VS versions.